# Why does `\iid` macro in OPmac only support "," or "."

Tags: plain-tex, opmac

To create an index entry in OPmac one enters something like this:

`Oh, how I like \ii figs figs.`

Notice the repetition there?  As a convenience OPmac provides `\iid`:

`Oh, how I like \iid figs .`

In this case, I didn't need to repeat the word "figs", though I did have to enter a space between the "s" and the "." in order for the sentence to be typeset correctly.

Unfortunately, the following does not typeset correctly:

`Oh, does anyone else like \iid figs ?`

In this case, instead of "figs?" being typeset, we get "figs ?" - with that space.

The culprit seems to be here:

`\def\iiD{\ifx\tmp,\else\ifx\tmp.\else\space\fi\fi}`  % comma and period handled

I modified to include a question mark ("?") with

`\def\iiD{\ifx\tmp,\else\ifx\tmp.\else\ifx\tmp?\else\space\fi\fi\fi}`

but obviously other punctuation such as exclamation points, colons, semi-colons, etc are needed.  Is there a better way to handle this perhaps?

Comment: Of course, you can redefine `\iiD` but you need to use the right number of `\fi`s at the end of the macro. IMHO the other punctuation isn't frequent, than you can use `\ii figs figs?` or `\iid figs \unskip?`. Of course, you can use the claccical approach with braces and repeation: `\iindex{figs}figs?`.

Comment: @wipet -- I fixed the missing `\fi` in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility to redefine the `\iid` macro in order to do it more intelligent. The point is that the parameter of `\iid` is separated by space (instead of two braces) in order to spare typing. But may be, two braces are useful sometimes.

```
\let\iidC=\iid
\def\iid {\futurelet\next\iidA}
\def\iidA {\ifx\next\bgroup \expandafter \iidB\else \expandafter \iidC \fi}
\def\iidB #1{\iindex{#1}#1}
```

Now you can use `\iid word` followed by space or `\iid {word}` without following space. In your case: `\iid{figs}?`.